# Are there any disadvantages of performing a hypothesis test at the lowest possible significance level that still rejects the null hypothesis?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

Suppose some researcher does a hypothesis test at a 10% significance level, and the conclusion is to reject $ H_0 $. Then the researcher does the exact same test again, on the exact same dataset, but just lowers the significance level to 5%, and keeps lowering it until the result changes. If it still returns to reject $ H_0 $, are there any issues whatsoever with saying "there is a (e.g.) ~1.5% probability of type I error", as if the first test at 10% was never conducted?

Has the power or otherwise reliability of the test been affected by lowering the significance value on the same dataset?

Comment: The lowest-possible significance level at which rejection can occur is the p-value (up to a factor of $2$ for two-tailed tests). And yes, what you propose is a problem, though the "why" warrants an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: There's an issue with your characterization of a p-value as a "probability of type I error," because that is not what it is.  At best the p-value is indirectly related to a hypothetical probability of a Type I error *supposing the null hypothesis holds* (along with many other attendant assumptions).  Indeed, if--based on a small p-value--you decide to reject the null, you are flatly contradicting yourself by quoting a probability calculated on the assumption the null is true!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a form of the [Texas Sharpshooter Fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_sharpshooter_fallacy).

If you just report a p-value and let the reader decide if it is significant or not (or even if they want to declare significance or not) and don't make any objective decisions/declarations based on the p-value, then that is reasonable.

But when you indicate that the test was done at a specific significance level, say 5%, then you are saying that before collecting the data (before randomization) there was a 5% chance of declaring significance/rejecting the null hypothesis if in fact the null hypothesis is True.  In your scenario, with a true null hypothesis a p-value of 0.09 would have lead to a declaration of significance, so the probability of rejecting when the null is true is 10%, to say that it was 1.5% is dishonest.